# Should datagrid and dataform bind to a PagedCollectionView or an ObservableCollection

Tags: silverlight

If I bind a datagrid and a dataform to the same ItemsSource I assumed that as I select different rows in the datagrid, the selected item would be displayed in the dataform.

It appears this only true if the data source is a PagedCollectionView and not an ObservableCollection?  Is that correct?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`ICollectionView` exposes members to handle a selected item and for moving between items.  An `ObservableCollection` is just a generic list with the added ability to throw an event on change.  The DataGrid relies on the SelectedItem functionality of a `ICollectionView` to know what the DataGrid has selected.

Note that the DataGrid always uses an `ICollectionView` to represent its Items.  If you provided an `ICollectionView` as the ItemsSource it will use that object but if you provide any other `IEnumerable` it will wrap it in its own internal `ICollectionView`

Comment: +1: The internal `ICollectionView` is a `PagedCollectionView`